# How to pass value by reference in xpath where the values are imported from external excel sheet in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a functional flow where I am adding a project and then confirming if it gets added successfully.
My web form has 3 fields (say fld1, fld2, fld3). I created an external excel sheet from where fld1 fld2 and fld3 values are called and entered into the form and submit happens. The steps I am automating is:

1. Step 1. Import fld1, fld2 and fld3 from excel sheet row 1 into the
   form (I am able to do this)
2. Step 2. Submit it.(I am able to do this)
3. Step 3. Check the project gets added.(Not able to do this one.)
4. Step 4. Again perform step 1 with row 2 data and do step 2 and so
   on.

The UI of the form1 is it has 3 fields say fld1, fld2, fld3 and a grid below these fields to show already added projects and once a project gets added it starts displaying in this grid as last row of the grid. Once we  import all 3 fields from excel sheet on form 1 and do submit, after click on submit an iframe window opens that shows % uploaded and once its uploaded 100% user needs to click on close button and iframe classes and user is on form 1 again and the project is added as the very last row of the grid. Till here I am able to automate.
I want to check of project is added or no. For this I tried using assert but am not sure how to pass value by reference in xpath. If I hardcode it then the script fails for row 2 of excel sheet for second iteration.My question is how should I pass value by reference in either findElement By id or using assert condition.
The code is here:

```
String projectName = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 200);
FileInputStream IPLinkFile = new FileInputStream(new File("xlsx sheet location"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(TestIPLFile);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Test");
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
  Row row = rowIterator.next();
  Thread.sleep(500);
  driver.findElement(By.id("InsertButtonID")).click();
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("pname1ID")));
  Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
  while (cellIterator.hasNext())
  {
    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
    if (cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
    {
      driver.findElement (By.id("pname1ID")).clear();
      projectName = cell.getStringCellValue();
      driver.findElement (By.id("pname1ID")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1)
    {
      Thread.sleep(500);
      driver.findElement(By.id("gvhost1ID")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("gvhost1ID")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==2)
    {
      Thread.sleep(500);
      driver.findElement(By.id("gcTest1")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("gcTest1")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  driver.findElement(By.id("btnUpdateImportID")).click();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  driver.switchTo().frame("TestImportTest");
  driver.findElement(By.id("form1"));
  driver.findElement(By.id("btnClose")).click();
  System.out.println("**********User uploaded IPLink Project successfully**********"+projectName);
  driver.navigate().refresh();
  Thread.sleep(500);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'GridDataID']//td[contains(text(), 'TestAuto1')]"));
  System.out.println("**********User uploaded IPLTest Projects found**********"+projectName);
}
```

I am using selenium with java and testNG.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support natural reference passing. Instead, to pass a value by reference, you must generate a pointer the object. The pointer can then be passed to the appopriate function. You can do this using a pointer object, defined in an API or by encapsulating the data in an object. By passing the object you will be passing the reference. In effect all object passes are reference passes, and all nonobject passes are value passes.

Comment: I am not sure how I can pass the reference in the below selenium command:driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'GridDataID']//td[contains(text(), 'TestAuto1')]")); The way I can think of is store the project name into a variable and pass that variable into last 2 code lines but not sure if I can do that in driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'GridDataID']//td[contains(text(), 'TestAuto1')]"));